# Register service implementation in SimpleIOC in PCL

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light, portable-class-library

I'm trying to register a service at the SimpleIOC that comes with MVVMLight. I have the ViewModelLocator in a PCL. I want to register a service from within my main project.

I'm working on Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight and try to implement/register a navigation service.

```
public interface INavigationService
{
    void Navigate(string uri);
    void Navigate(string uri, Dictionary<string, string> parameters);
    void GoBack();
}
```

Implementation of my service interface:

```
public class NavigationService : INavigationService
{
    public NavigationService()
    {

    }

    public void Navigate(string uri)
    {
        DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            () => ((PhoneApplicationFrame)   Application.Current.RootVisual).Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative)));
    }

    public void Navigate(string uri, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void GoBack()
    {
        DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            () => ((PhoneApplicationFrame) Application.Current.RootVisual).GoBack());
    }
}
```

This is how I register the service at the IOC container from within my App.xaml.cs (OnLaunching method)

```
// init the dispatcher helper for MVVM usage
DispatcherHelper.Initialize();

// add some platform specific services to the IOC container
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService, NavigationService>();
```

And this is the error message that I can when starting my app:

```
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException: Cannot register: No public constructor found in NavigationService.
at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc.GetConstructorInfo(Type serviceType)
at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc.Register[TInterface,TClass](Boolean createInstanceImmediately)
at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc.Register[TInterface,TClass]()
at TimeStamp.WindowsPhone.App.Application_Launching(Object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.FireLaunching()
at Microsoft.Phone.TaskModel.Interop.Task.FireOnLaunching()
```

As I have a constructor in my NavigationService it seems that something obvious which I don't see is missing here.

Btw.: I want to use that service from within my main view model:

```
/// <summary>
/// Default constructor
/// </summary>
/// <param name="workDayServiceAgent"></param>
[PreferredConstructor]
public MainViewModel(IWorkDayServiceAgent workDayServiceAgent, INavigationService navigationService)
{
    // set the service agents
    _workDayServiceAgent = workDayServiceAgent;
    _navigationService = navigationService;
    ...
```

Comment: Is that the only constructor you have in NavigationService? Does marking ctor with [PreferredConstructor] attribute fix the problem?

Comment: Yes, this is the only ctor in there. I just added it because of this error message although it is not required. But this actually didn't change anything. R# even suggests to remove it again.

Comment: Try registering the service in ViewModelLocater constructor

Comment: I would like to do that but it is not possible (at least I don't see how). The reason is that my ViewModeLocator is in the PCL (including INavigationService). But NavigationService (the platform specific implementation) is **not** in the PCL. It is in the Windows Phone project. I can not put it into PCL because it uses the platform specific navigation mechanisms. But maybe I just don't understand how MVVMLight services are used. But my understanding tells me that the service interface is in the PCL and the actual implementation is always in the platform specific projects, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more than two hours of more research in my code I figured out what the actual issue is. When registering NavigationService I'm actually not using my own implementation but System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService. After renaming my NavigationService to NavigationServiceWP everything works fine.